# rspec helper.stub doesn't work

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm developing Rails 3.1.1, Ruby 1.9.2 and testing with Rspec2.
Stubbing in helper doesn't work.

**users_helper_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersHelper do
  describe 'test' do
    before do
      helper.stub(:val).and_return('this is test')  
    end

    it 'returns val' do
      test.should eql 'this is test'
    end
  end
end
```

**user_helper.rb**

```
module UsersHelper
  def test
    return val
  end
end
```

**error**

```
1) UsersHelper test test
   Failure/Error: test.should eql 'this is test'
   NameError:
     undefined local variable or method `val' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_15::Nested_1:0x007f9ad5f42a50>
   # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:3:in `test'
   # ./spec/helpers/users_helper_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Stubbing in controller and view works properly, but in helper it doesn't work.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you stubbing the very value that you're trying to test? This doesn't appear to make sense. If you can show us some actual code instead of a contrived example, perhaps we can help more... Also, it's probably more readable to use `==` instead of `eql`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought this is the easiest way to show what the problem is and that the problem doesn't depend on what another code is.

Comment: But it isn't. Since we can't see your actual code, we can't make good guesses about what's going on. Please provide your actual code.

Comment: I'm sorry that I bothered you. I've solved myself.

Comment: The question may not have been posed perfectly, but this answer was definitely not attempting to answer the question. Perhaps this could have been a comment on the question instead?

Comment: @thekingoftruth I was indeed attempting to answer the question (don't assume that you can read my mind! :) ), but the question didn't appear to make sense, so I couldn't do so without more clarification. Perhaps this should have been a comment; I'm not sure at this point.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersHelper do
  describe 'test' do
    before do
      helper.stub(:val).and_return('this is test')  
    end

    it 'returns val' do
      helper.test.should eql 'this is test'
      # helper. is required.
    end
  end
end
```

helper.test works fine.

[#199: Can't stub method calls in helpers - Issues - rspec/rspec-rails - GitHub](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/199)